# Connection String used by Oracle Database Net Services

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to connect to an Oracle database from my local machine(note which doesn't has oracle installed on it) using SQL* plus CLI tool.
I'm using below connection string as parameters to be passed to the host.

sqlplus "user_name/password_@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=server_name)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME=SID)))"

However the user name i am getting connected is having a Kerberos based authentication , hence above command is giving me below connection error.
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified..

Is there a way i can append the above connection string to mention that the incoming hadnshake is "Kerberos based". Or in other terms can JDBC read this kerberos based authentication in any way..

Below is the connection snapshot from SQL Developer.

[Connection Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL9kb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [Kerberos authentication](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/client-side-security.html#GUID-97E88D18-B590-4313-87B8-EE422DA644B3) section in JDBC developers guide.